# Disable UIWebView to play video in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to avoid auto video playing in `MPMoviePlayerController`
is there any possible way to stop webview not to load video in  full screen and `MPMoviePlayerController` ? I used this codes in `viewDidLoad` but still no success !

```
    webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = true
    webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = false
```

Comment: UIWebView will NOT auto-play any video by default. Please check your javascript/html code

Comment: @SivajeeBattina Yes , my mistake ! but is there any possible way to avoid movie playing at all ? even in MPMoviePlayerController

Comment: Yes. Can you please paste your javascript or html code here

Comment: @SivajeeBattina it is from different websites youtube , vimeo , and etc... any website which has video content

Comment: Understood your problem @Mc.Love. can you please try [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.querySelector('video').pause();"]

Comment: @SivajeeBattina Still open videos in  `MPMoviePlayerController` What I am trying here is I need to get video URL with `AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification`  In this case I have to play video first to get its `URL` but I need to get URL without going in MPMovie....

Comment: AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification is use in WKWebView ? if yes how can i do that please see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview